# How to add decimal values to entries for chart using MpAndroidChart Library?

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart, linechart

I'm trying to create a line chart in Android using **MPAndroidChart Library** and as entries I have values like 1200.10, 1300.70 and so on, but on my chart the values are **rounded (1200, 1301)**, and I want to display the original values. How can I do that? I tried different solutions but couldn't solve the problem yet. I'm using the Kotlin language. Thanks!

```
 for (item in reversedCashList) {
        if (i <= daysNmb) {
            var cashValue: String = transformDataForChart(item.value!!)
            dataValsEntries.add(Entry(i, cashValue.toFloat()))
            i++
        }
 }
```

**Also, I'm using this formatter Class to format my values because the initial format is like 120.200,10 and I changed them to 120200.10 but this values is displayed as 120200. My Formatter Class:**

```
private fun transformDataForChart(totalValue: String): String {
    return if (totalValue.contains(".")) {
        val test = totalValue.replace(".", "")
        test.replace(",", ".")
    } else {
        totalValue.replace(",", ".")
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code where you adding your decimal values

Comment: I edited the question, please take a look. thanks

Comment: val test = totalValue.replace(".", "") why are you replacing "." with ""(emty string)

Comment: I don't understand why the values are automatically rounded..

Comment: just return the value as it is. you got decimal values right, just return it. it will wont change.  you replacing "." with empty string in this transformDataForChart() thats why it rounded the value to integer(without ".")

Comment: Because if the initial number is 120.200,10 and I have to transform this number to 120200.10 so it can be displayed on the Chart, otherwise I get an exception

Comment: @Razvan22 Try to convert them to Double not Float :)

Comment: Where I change the "." to empty string it's not for decimals, decimals are separated with "," in the original values.

Comment: @Septimiu I tried but the Entry() class of the MpAndroidChart Library accept only Float as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [BigDecimal](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal), something like `BigDecimal.valueOf(X).setScale(decimalPlace(usually 2), BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).floatValue()`

The idea is that float cannot hold so many values as the Double, I've encountered this issue as some point as well, and I had to change everything to Double just to make it more easier to maintain... Therefor I don't think is a straight-forward method to keep everything you need in the float format.

Comment: Where should I use this?

Comment: Example: 
val number = "1200.12".toDouble()

val res = BigDecimal.valueOf(number).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toFloat()

So I think you should put cashValue instead of number in my example :D